# Name of pattern used in google maps > activity after scrolling become full screen activity

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns

what's the name of pattern that is use in google maps?
[image]

after scrolling this activity go to the top.
Android SDK provide some solution or I need to implement this on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the correct name for the pattern you're looking for, but [`AndroidSlidingUpPanel`](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) is a library doing exactly what you're looking for.

[image]